# Is it possible to seperate cells like based on a variable?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, cooling

Here I have 2 pages one named Input and The other Output

in Input I have In cell C2 the number of lanes which is 6 in this example and the D2 the number of Heats which is currently 4 :

[image: I can't embed photos yet so this is a link to it]

if this translated to Output it will look something like this:
[image: same old link]
as you can see (if you clicked the link the is a 6 cells gape between every Heat (this is the code for the heats btw
[
`Heat 1 -> =IF(ROW()<=Input!$D$2,"Heat "&ROW(),"")`
`Heat 2 -> =IF(ROW()-Input!C2<=Input!$D$2,"Heat "&ROW()-Input!C2,"")`
`Heat 3 -> =IF(ROW()-(Input!C2*2)<=Input!$D$2,"Heat "&ROW()-(Input!C2*2),"")`
`Heat 4 -> =IF(ROW()-(Input!C2*3)<=Input!$D$2,"Heat "&ROW()-(Input!C2*3),"")`
]

My question is there a way that if the change the number of lanes in the Input file to a higher number the number of cell gape in the Output file increase and vice versa (as shown in this link if the number of lanes is now 8:
[image: if the number of lanes is 8]
if the number of lanes is 8) and if yes how can I do it subsequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign named ranges "Heats" and "Lanes" to the two values (or replace them in the formula below).

I am assuming this formula starts in cell A1 and is then dragged down to some reasonable number of rows.

If you start in a row other than row 1, change the "=1" in the formula to "=". You could also do this with another named range if you prefer.
This formula fills every cell in the column rather than leaving empty cells in between of course. But if feels like you could make this column very narrow (eg width = 1) and use it just for the headings, then add other text to column B eg competitor names.

```
=IF(ROW()<(Lanes*(Heats+1)), IF(MOD(ROW(),Heats+1)=1, "Heat" & INT(ROW()/Lanes)+1, ""),"")
```